# How can I create an Countdown Timer that when it reaches 0 goes up again with javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I know nothing about javascripting, I am an internship trying to make a countdown timer. When it reaches 0 it would go up again until someone presses space bar to stop and start, if it is even possible of course. Can you  help me out? I know it sounds like do it for me job but please help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing or tutorial service

Comment: Sorry if I dont know nothing about coding , just because you know it doesnt mean this site isnt for helping others , this website isnt just for people who know coding and only helping each other so your point is invalid .

Comment: No, it isn't. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: So this site inst for people who know nothing about coding just for the people who know, thats what your saying?

Comment: *"for professional and enthusiast programmers"*

Comment: Well Im an enthusiast programmer trying to know more about coding, but without help I cant do that.
I wonder one thing you answer all my comments but cant help me. wow

Comment: Frankly, it's not really your skill level or professional status that's crucial, but the *quality of your questions*; this is a lazy question, showing no thought or research whatsoever.

Comment: Like I said it sounds like do it for me but noone of my work know about coding so they said go ask in stackoverflow they will answer

Comment: If they don't know about coding, why take their word on SO? It *"sounds like do it for me"* because **that's what you're asking**. Again, please read [ask], and the other content in the Help Center; I see no point in continuing this conversation.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var time = 60;

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test()
{
    //update time
    time -=1;
    //update the div to show the time
    $('#testDiv').html(time); 

    //hide the div if the time is 0
    if(time == 0)        
    {
        $('#testDiv').remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include jQuery lib;

Comment: This does not answer the question and even if it did, it would still be a bad answer.